# How to remove canvas objects from memory with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, canvas, memory

**Note: I have edited my original post because the problem is not iOS related but more a general thing.**

I'm creating an application with JavaScript which cuts an image into several pieces via canvas.

I have two steps:

1. Choose image (from existing or upload new)
2. Cut image into pieces by using canvas

If I'm doing the process several times I notice that many canvas are created in the memory. I'm checking that by using the developer tools in Safari and then selecting the tab "Canvas".
The problem is, that those canvas items are really adding up. If I first cut the image into 10 pieces and in the next round I'm cutting into 20 pieces, then I have 30 canvas items in my memory.

My goal is to **remove / clear the existing canvas by clearing the memory** (or whatever the best way is) because otherwise I will face memory issues soon.

I already tried removing the canvas by removing it from the DOM and setting the variable to null:

```
var myCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
myCanvas.parentElement.removeChild(myCanvas);
myCanvas = null;
```

The problem here is that if I now upload an image from my computer, the canvas still adds up in the memory. The previously cut pieces (canvas items) are still there and not removed:

[image]

Furthermore, since I removed the canvas element from the DOM, the sliced pieces don't show up on the page anymore. They're only in the "Canvas" tab in the dev tools.

I also tried clearing the canvas:

```
// this.ctx is the canvas
this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.ctx.canvas.width, 
this.ctx.canvas.height);
this.ctx.canvas.height = 0;
this.ctx.canvas.width = 0;
this.ctx = null;
```

It somehow resets the canvas but doesn't remove it from the memory, so it's useless for me.

If I refresh the page, the memory is cleared of course but I will use this in a mobile app later so that's not an option for me.

Any idea how to solve this?
Thank you so much in advance for any help!

Comment: Hmm in what way are the images being manupulated? In your screenshot the boxes show sizes between 6 and 11MB. Possibly the original ones are fine but they're growing or leaking somewhere?

Comment: @Gavin The image is cut into jigsaw puzzle pieces. The canvas has a width of 1024px, the original ones have a width of around 500px. I would understand if the canvas is round 2-5 MB but 11 MB is a bit too much I guess.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I mean "navigating" between pages, I'm using the Angular router for that. Sorry for being unclear.